# Oozie job fails to run due to impersonation error (wild card support)

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I'm not able to run an oozie job on local single node hadoop cluster despite setting the user "kapil.sharma02" as a proxy user. Is this due to wild card in my user name? Can you please suggest a remedy?

kapil.sharma02$ ./oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config ../examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run

**Error: E0501 : E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, User: kapil.sharma02 is not allowed to impersonate kapil.sharma02**

**Here is my core-site.xml (hadoop 2.6.4)** 
I have tried adding this config both with and without escape character but no luck.

```
<configuration>
   <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>

<property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.kapil\.sharma02.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>

 <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.kapil\.sharma02.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
 </property>

   <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>                                  
      <value>*</value>
    </property>

 <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
 </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your job log for proper failure information. I am not sure whether this may help you, but similar issue is resolved [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Oozie-Error-E0501-User-oozie-is-not-allowed-to-impersonate-root/td-p/4259). please have a look.

Comment: I just want to know how do I handle the wild card issue in my name. Escape is not working as indicated in code above.